# Hard drive not appearing in'places'

Tags: hard-drive

My Samsung hard drive does not appear in 'places' when I do 'save as'.  Here is the output from `sudo lsblk`. How do i save a file to my Samsung drive?

```
NAME    FSTYPE  LABEL    UUID                                  MOUNTPOINT
sda
├─sda1  vfat             482C-5E60                             /boot/efi
├─sda2  ext4             60458131-491a-417f-987e-d7ee97f07234  /
└─sda3  swap             9521ad31-127d-4b8e-baa3-5a0643429b13  [SWAP]
sdb
└─sdb1  ntfs    SAMSUNG  9EA45B47A45B2157                      /media/stuart/SAMSUNG
sr0
```

Comment: Is it mounted and accessible?

Comment: I can navigate to it and see content, but can't see it to save to.